# Retrieve data from a view is very time consuming using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-server-2016

I've created a `view` in SQL server 2016. The view is created with the statement:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.StockEOMonth
AS
   SELECT       CAST(StoreKey AS numeric(4, 0)) AS StoreKey, 
                DateKey, 
                SUM(StockValue) AS StockValue,
                SUM(StockQuantity) AS StockQuantity
   FROM         Stock
   WHERE        CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(10), DateKey)) = 
                EOMONTH(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(10), DateKey)))
   GROUP BY DateKey, storekey
```

The view itself is rather straight-forward. I return the total `StockQuantity` and `StockValue` balance for each Store at the last day of the month (the reason why I use SUM() is because the underlying table, `Stock`, includes the balances for each Product but I am only interested in the total balance for each store).

This view returns merely `4000` records. However, when I use the Query:

```
SELECT top(10) StockValue, StockQuantity 
FROM dbo.StockEOMonth
```

the Query takes 13 *minutes* to return only 10 rows.

I'm not sure how to optimize such a trivial view. Does anyone have an idea? I could create the table as an actual table, but it would like to have it as a `view` if possible.

> EDIT

I've experianced the slowness in retrieving data in both `SSMS` and `SSAS` where I have gotten `ErrorCode 3240034318` from the instance where I've started to use the view as a data source for a measure Group, where the ErrorCode seem to be related to Query TimeOut.

Comment: i create a test table ,and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE clause is not SARGable. You should remove the function on the left side of the where clause:

```
WHERE DateKey = EOMONTH(DateKey)
```

If the formatting doesn't work, put functions on the right to make it match the format of DateKey.

If you haven't already tuned the indexes, try this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_test] ON [stock]
(
    [datekey] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [StoreKey],
    [StockValue],
    [StockQuantity]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't know about the term SARGable. DateKey is of data type numeric(8,0) in my case. I've tried to alter the where clause to become `DateKey = cast(convert(varchar,eomonth(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(10), DateKey))),112) as numeric(8,0))`. SSMS is processing the Query at the moment. I'll see what happens

Comment: The answer has been updated to include an appropriate index.